# The method addElement is undefined for the type LinkedList

Tags: java, eclipse, undefined

I am working on an assignment and I'm trying to add an element to a LinkedList. The first block of code is given and should not be changed. The second block is written according to the UML given to us by the professor and is located in another class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Assignment10
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       char input1;
       String inputInfo = new String();
       int operation2;
       String line = new String();

       //create a linked list to be used in this method.
       LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();

       try
        {
         // print out the menu
         printMenu();

         // create a BufferedReader object to read input from a keyboard
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
         BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (isr);

         do
          {
           System.out.print("What action would you like to perform?\n");
           line = stdin.readLine().trim();  //read a line
           input1 = line.charAt(0);
           input1 = Character.toUpperCase(input1);

           if (line.length() == 1)   // check if a user entered only one character
            {
             switch (input1)
              {
               case 'A':   //Add String
                 System.out.print("Please enter a string to add:\n");
                 String str1 = stdin.readLine().trim();
                 System.out.print("Please enter an index to add:\n");
                 inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
                 int addIndex = Integer.parseInt(inputInfo);
                 list1.addElement(addIndex, str1);
                 break;

public void addElement(int index, Object element)
   {
       if(index < 0)
       {
           IndexOutOfBoundsException ex = new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
           throw ex;
       }
       LinkedListIterator iterator = new LinkedListIterator();
       for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
       {
           if(iterator.hasNext())   // check if the iterator has a next value before
               iterator.next(); // moving to next element
           else
           {
               NoSuchElementException exception = new NoSuchElementException();
               throw exception;
           }
       }                    
       iterator.add(element);
   } // end of addElement
```

Here is what Eclipse is telling me:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method addElement(int, String) is undefined for the type LinkedList.

Again, I am not supposed to change the first block of code so there must be something wrong with my addElement method. Any ideas? Sorry this isn't compilable, but this is really more of a conceptual question, I think.

Comment: Can you add more code? What type is `list1`? where is `main` function?

Comment: If `list1` is a `LinkedList` there is no method named `addElement(int, String)`

Comment: Done, list1 is a LinkedList.

Comment: There is method name `add(int, Object)` to add object on `LinkedList` data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that someone is confused.

- On the one hand, you appear to be *implementing* a method called `addElement` on what appears to be a custom list implementation.  (You don't show us the entire class ...)
- On the other hand, you appear to be trying to call a nonexistent `addElement` on the standard `java.util.LinkedList` class.

One of these things is clearly wrong.  Either you have misunderstood what you are supposed to do, or your lecturer has given you a test harness class (`Assignment10`) that is incorrect.  (Yes lecturers do make mistakes.  They are only human.)

I suggest you ask your lecturer or your tutor for clarification.  (And please be polite and deferential.  There is nothing more annoying for a lecturer than a student who is "in his face" about errors, especially imaginary ones.)

Comment: I agree, I am confused. But I have seen a working program and the main method code is correct. I think the error is on my part, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Without seeing what you were asked to do and what you have actually done, it is hard to know what you've done wrong.  And going to that level of detail is outside the scope of SO Questions, IMO.  Do you have a "programming advisor" or "tutor" to ask for help?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to get this done this weekend. I've emailed the TA and I'll go to their help hours.

Comment: It turns out that I should not have imported LinkedList in the assignment 10 file.